# .htaccess password on root not working

Tags: .htaccess

i'm trying to apply a site password to the root directory of my site:

www.example.com

I have my .htpasswd file in the same directory as the .htaccess file (public_html) and my .htaccess file has the following code:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "This Area is Password Protected"
AuthUserFile /public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

With this code it prompts for credentials however when I enter the correct credentials it takes me to a server error page. Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: Pretty sure `/public_html/.htpasswd` is the wrong path - I doubt that you have `public_html` at the very root of your file system …?

Comment: could be, I dont have root access unfortuantely so what would generally be at the root?

Comment: Where your public_html folder is located, can differ between system. Check the hoster’s documentation resp. the account data they send you, or use something like `phpinfo()` and check what document root is indicated in the output.

Comment: the document root from phpinfo() is kunden/homepages/0/d293994/htdocs/mysite. Shoud the AuthUserFile be kunden/homepages/0/d293994/htdocs/mysite/public_html/.htpasswd?

Comment: Yes, but with a leading slash - `/kunden/homepages/…`

Comment: hmm still no joy im afraid

Comment: Do you have access to the error log? And how did you create the .htpasswd file?